# Can't access id on Backbone model on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

**Problem:**
I am mirroring resourceful models in Rails with Backbone.js.I'm trying to get the current user id to a Backbone Workshop.Models.User model so I can save the user to the database through the Rails users RESTful resource. I can't retrieve the id from the Currentuser model. ?

I my return value is undefined when I try to retrieve the id of an instance of the current user model in Backbone. I can see on the server log that the fetch is successful and I can inspect the object if I output the local instance into the log. I can even use the console to run the same code and successfully get the id. It's only at runtime.

I suspect I'm supposed to configure my models differently or bind something in my view. Help?

[See my gist here](https://gist.github.com/4218882)

**Models:**

```
# singleton model gets current user

class Workshop.Models.Currentuser extends Backbone.Model
idAttribute: '_id'
urlRoot: -> '/user/currentuser/'

# classic Rails RESTful resource

class Workshop.Models.User extends Backbone.Model
urlRoot: '/users/show'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your gist, you have the following code

```
current_user = new Workshop.Models.Currentuser
current_user.fetch()
console.log(current_user.id)
```

however, fetch is asnychronous and the `id` won't be filled in until the ajax call is done.

Try this (apologize because my ruby skills are zero and my coffeescript is not so good either so no guarantee on syntax)

`current_user.fetch({
    success: -> console.log(current_user.id)
});`

Comment: That would explain why it works in the console. I have to get usef to thinking with evented code.